# call render sign_in in the index page devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to call a render of `sign_in` in my index page.

I don't want to go to another page I want to stay in the same page.

I have tried:

```
<%= render :partial ... %>

<%= render :file %>
```

I get an error.

Do you have any idea to how I can do that?

---

my file in devise/sessions/_new.html.erb

```
 <h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

if i put content_for on the file i get an error do you know how i can render the file in my index after clicking on the link .

Comment: For a start let us know what error did you get? For example `<%= render 'reset_password_modal' %>` renders a file called _reset_password_modal.html.erb in the same view directory. If you want to render a file from another directory you need to add it in front like `<%= render 'dir_name/reset_password_modal' %>`

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

If you want to render a partial view inside another view, save it with a `_` prefix. So call your file:

`_sign_in.html.erb`

To render a partial as part of a view use the render method within the view:

```
<%= render "sign_in" %>
```

If it is not in the same folder as the other views of that controller, i.e. called 'shared' :

```
<%= render "shared/sign_in" %>
```

For more information:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: What is not working? Can you put the error log and describe where the file your trying to render is located? With such few information no one will be able to help you